# My app doesn't run on iphone 6 with ios ver 8.3

Tags: ios, ios8

I have an application at the AppStore, is was compiled using xcode 5.1.1 with target platform 6.0.

downloading it to iphone 4,5 with all IOS versions works fine.

downloading it to iphone 6 with IOS 8.3, when running the application it get stuck on the splash screen

any ideas?

Comment: May be the architecture would be the reason.

Comment: @ViralSavaj what do you mean? and what can I do to make it work on these devices with the current version at the store?

Answer (score 0):

Your App Target configuration should use "Standard architectures" like this:

- Architecture: "Standard architectures" arm7, arm64
- Valid Architectures: "arm64" , armv7, armv7s
- Build Active Architecture Only - NO

You can see configuration like [THIS](http://postimg.org/image/rrdcm3ovh/)

May Help You.

HTH, Enjoy Coding!!

Comment: these are my exact configurations